# scp, globbing, and different shells

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, zsh, wildcards

The other day at work I tried doing

```
scp remotehost:~/*.txt .
```

and I received an error about the  `*`, `*.txt file not found` *sorry, not at work and I forget the exact error*

on my workstation I run `zsh` 4.3. on the remotehost `bash` is the default shell, and the version of `zsh` is older (*4.2* vs *4.3*) on that. I then tried switching to bash on my workstation, and doing the exact same command. This time it worked. What is the root 'cause of this. Is there anyway to do globbing, or wildcards between these 2 systems (without switching to bash)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

zsh's behavior is a little different here than most other shells. Other shells, like bash, try to expand the wildcards. If they cannot expand to anything they pass the literal string (containing the wildcards) to the application instead. But zsh does not do that (well, there is an option for that, to do it or not). The zsh will print that error and not perform the command. You can override that by escaping the wildcard, if you really want it passed to the application. In this case you do since you want the other side shell to expand it. So use

```
scp remotehost:\*.txt .
```

or use quoting,

```
scp 'remotehost:*.txt' .
```

or use the `zsh`-specific `noglob` "precommand modifier" (the shell will not try to expand any globs in the command),

```
noglob scp remotehost:*.txt .
```

This is actually the correct behavior, since if you did have some local *.txt files in your home they would be expanded to a name that might not exist on the remote. That's not what you want.

Comment: know the option to change the default behavior?

Comment: @xeno it's the nomatch, which you unset with the NO_NOMATCH option. In bash there is a `failglob` option as well. The difference is the default behavior. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#l9

Comment: you can also put the thing with * in double quotes